# android scorecard - sharedpreferences and display

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I am now working on a 4 players' scorecard where the user input the scores for the 4 players at the bottom of the page and when press the + button, the scores just input will then add to the scrollview above.

slot number is defined as the round number, such that when the user input into the corresponding EditText as 1, 12, 34, 56, 78 the app can recognize and add a row for slot =1, then Player 1 score would be 12, player 2 would be 34, P3 = 56, P4 = 78.

and then when the user input another set like 2, 23, 45, 67, 89 it will add as round 2 and so on.
so far the row can be added properly, the slot number can be 1, 2, 3 and so on, but don't know why

for round 1: slot number correct as 1, but all the 4 Player scores as input above become 78,

for round 2: slot number correct as 2, but all the 4 Player scores as input above become 89.

```
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
   {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
      setContentView(R.layout.main);

      // get the SharedPreferences that contains the user's saved slots 
      SavedSlotsP1 = getSharedPreferences("slots", MODE_PRIVATE);
      SavedSlotsP2 = getSharedPreferences("slots", MODE_PRIVATE);
      SavedSlotsP3 = getSharedPreferences("slots", MODE_PRIVATE);
      SavedSlotsP4 = getSharedPreferences("slots", MODE_PRIVATE);

      SlotTableLayout = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.SlotTableLayout);  
      SlotEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.SlotEditText);
      P1ScoreEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.P1ScoreEditText);
      P2ScoreEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.P2ScoreEditText);
      P3ScoreEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.P3ScoreEditText);
      P4ScoreEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.P4ScoreEditText);

      refreshButtons(null);
   } // end method onCreate

public OnClickListener addButtonListener = new OnClickListener()
   // create a new Button and add it to the ScrollView   
   {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) 
      {
         if (SlotEditText.getText().length() > 0 &&
             P1ScoreEditText.getText().length() > 0 && 
             P2ScoreEditText.getText().length() > 0 &&
             P3ScoreEditText.getText().length() > 0 && 
             P4ScoreEditText.getText().length() > 0 )            
         {
            SaveTagToFile(SlotEditText.getText().toString(),
                    P1ScoreEditText.getText().toString(), 
                    P2ScoreEditText.getText().toString(), 
                    P3ScoreEditText.getText().toString(), 
                    P4ScoreEditText.getText().toString());

            SlotEditText.setText(""); 
            P1ScoreEditText.setText(""); 
            P2ScoreEditText.setText("");
            P3ScoreEditText.setText(""); 
            P4ScoreEditText.setText("");

            // hide the soft keyboard
            ((InputMethodManager) getSystemService(
               Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE)).hideSoftInputFromWindow(
               SlotEditText.getWindowToken(), 0);  
         } // end if
         else 
         {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(FavoriteTwitterSearches.this);
            builder.setTitle(R.string.missingTitle); 
            builder.setMessage(R.string.missingMessage);
            builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.OK, null);             
            AlertDialog errorDialog = builder.create();
            errorDialog.show();
         } 
      } 
   };    

   private void SaveTagToFile(String Slot, String P1Score, String P2Score, String P3Score, String P4Score)
   // save the new row to the file, then refresh all Buttons
   {
      // originalScore will be null if we're modifying an existing search
      String originalScoreP1 = SavedSlotsP1.getString(Slot, null);
      String originalScoreP2 = SavedSlotsP2.getString(Slot, null);
      String originalScoreP3 = SavedSlotsP3.getString(Slot, null);
      String originalScoreP4 = SavedSlotsP4.getString(Slot, null);

      // get a SharedPreferences.Editor to store new row data
      SharedPreferences.Editor preferencesEditorP1 = SavedSlotsP1.edit();
      SharedPreferences.Editor preferencesEditorP2 = SavedSlotsP2.edit();
      SharedPreferences.Editor preferencesEditorP3 = SavedSlotsP3.edit();
      SharedPreferences.Editor preferencesEditorP4 = SavedSlotsP4.edit();

      preferencesEditorP1.putString(Slot, P1Score);
      preferencesEditorP2.putString(Slot, P2Score);
      preferencesEditorP3.putString(Slot, P3Score);
      preferencesEditorP4.putString(Slot, P4Score);

      preferencesEditorP1.apply();
      preferencesEditorP2.apply();
      preferencesEditorP3.apply();
      preferencesEditorP4.apply();

      // if this is a new slot, add its GUI
      if (originalScoreP1 == null) //P1 imply also P2, P3, P4
          refreshButtons(Slot); 
   } 

private void refreshButtons(String ThereIsNewSlot)
   // recreate search tag and edit Buttons for all saved searches;
   // pass null in all circumstances to renew and recreate to show all the saved rows

   {
      // store saved tags in the tags array
      String[] slots = SavedSlotsP1.getAll().keySet().toArray(new String[0]);

      Arrays.sort(slots, String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER); // sort by slot

      // if a new row was added, insert in GUI at the appropriate location
      if (ThereIsNewSlot != null) {ToDisplayTagGUI(ThereIsNewSlot, Arrays.binarySearch(slots, ThereIsNewSlot));}
      else // recreate and display GUI for ALL tags
      {for (int index = 0; index < slots.length; ++index) ToDisplayTagGUI(slots[index], index);} 
   }

   private void ToDisplayTagGUI(String Slot, int index)
   // add a new tag button and corresponding edit button to the GUI   
   {
      LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
      View newTagView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.new_tag_view, null);

      EditText SlotNewTagEditText = (EditText) newTagView.findViewById(R.id.SlotNewTagEditText);
      EditText P1NewTagScoreEditText = (EditText) newTagView.findViewById(R.id.P1NewTagScoreEditText);
      EditText P2NewTagScoreEditText = (EditText) newTagView.findViewById(R.id.P2NewTagScoreEditText);
      EditText P3NewTagScoreEditText = (EditText) newTagView.findViewById(R.id.P3NewTagScoreEditText);
      EditText P4NewTagScoreEditText = (EditText) newTagView.findViewById(R.id.P4NewTagScoreEditText);
      Button newTagEditButton = (Button) newTagView.findViewById(R.id.NewTagEditButton); 

      String P1Score = SavedSlotsP1.getString(Slot, "");
      String P2Score = SavedSlotsP2.getString(Slot, "");
      String P3Score = SavedSlotsP3.getString(Slot, "");
      String P4Score = SavedSlotsP4.getString(Slot, ""); 

      SlotNewTagEditText.setText(""+Slot); // assume Slot for P1 = P2 = P3 = P4
      P1NewTagScoreEditText.setText(""+P1Score);
      P2NewTagScoreEditText.setText(""+P2Score); 
      P3NewTagScoreEditText.setText(""+P3Score); 
      P4NewTagScoreEditText.setText(""+P4Score); 

      // add new tag and edit buttons to queryTableLayout
      SlotTableLayout.addView(newTagView, index);
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using the same SharedPrefs and key for every player's score, so it's getting overridden with each successive write.

Either Change the prefs that are loaded for each player, or make the keys unique. I'd do the latter, which means you can also ditch the concept of a store for each player, and do something like this:

```
scoreStore = getSharedPreferences("scores", MODE_PRIVATE);

...

scoreEditor = scoreStore.edit();
scoreEditor.putString("p1score", p1score);
scoreEditor.putString("p2score", p2score);
scoreEditor.putString("p3score", p3score);
scoreEditor.putString("p4score", p4score);
scoreEditor.apply();
```